# how to run a program in eclipse with a different command other than "java"

Tags: java, command-line, args

Instead of the command:

```
java program.java args
```

Can I configure eclipse to run the program with something like:

```
MyCommand program.java args
```

Comment: In Eclipse you could try using "run > external tools > [configure your tool]" but it is hard to tell based on your example.

Comment: You can't run `java` files either way; and when you invoke a `class` file you don't include it in the command. What is `MyCommand`, and how does it start your java process? You **can** use [remote debugging](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/enable-remote-debugging.html) with eclipse.

Comment: You could make a copy of java.exe and name it something else.  Or you could write a .bat file that runs java.exe.